# Centralized batch job management java

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

- Currently, I have an idea about building a centralized batch job management system (I temporarily call it batch service).
- We own a microservice system, and the batch jobs are scattered across the services (including oracle's bacth jobs). So I intend to set up a bacth job management system.
- But there is one problem that in microservices there are many databases, so I want the manipulation of data to be done by other services, and batch service only does the following things: setting, scheduling, checking status state, log, start, stop, retry.
- My idea is to use message broker(kafka, rabbitmq, ...) to pass job request from batch service to other services. But I am not thinking of a solution to stop or save the log of jobs on the batch service.
- Is this idea feasible and if so can you give me some advice on deployment technologies (We are deploying using spring boot at the moment).

Thanks for taking the time to read ^^.

Comment: That already exists in the form of Spring Batch Admin and Spring Cloud Task.

Comment: I was about to post the same comment as M. Deinum. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try it. ^^

Comment: spring-batch-lightmin provides centralized administration of distributed spring batch jobs
https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin